# Is there a way to print notes from Tomboy?

Tags: tomboy

Is there a way to print out my Tomboy notes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a note open, click the tools (cog) icon and select **Print**.
[image]

If the option is not there, ensure printing support is enabled (it is by default):

- Edit > Preferences
- Add-ins tab
- Expand **Desktop Integration**
- Select **Printing Support** and click **Enable**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As everyone says, Printing Support can be enabled for individual notes only, a screenshot is placed here for your convenience:

[image]

If you find a way to print several notes at once please let me know.

Thank you and Good luck!