# Print Tomboy notes recursively

Tags: printing, tomboy

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26831/is-there-a-way-to-print-notes-from-tomboy) on how to print notes from Tomboy, and that's all very well.

However, I have a "root note" with a contents list of a log book I've been keeping for a project. The contents list has links to all the log entries, which are in their own separate notes.

Is there any way I can make Tomboy "traverse" all these notes and print them for me in one command?

I want the solution to follow all links in each note, but never print the same note more than once (most of the log entries have a link back to the root entry, creating a loop...). Also, I will probably end up printing this to a pdf file anyway, so if there is a way to export the notes in this fashion into a *single, human-readable* file that does not enable printing directly, that's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the option 'export to html'. From your 'root note', click the 'gears' icon, and select 'export to html. At the bottom of the dialog that opens asking you where to save the file, you get two options to tick: 'export linked notes', and 'include all other linked notes'. The first is presumably what you want. Also tick the second option if you want Tomboy to follow all the links in the linked notes (and not only those in your 'root note'). Then print from the page that opens in your web browser.

You might have to enable the 'export html' add-in from the Tomboy preferences.

Comment: Fantastic! The formatting is pretty ugly, but it's good enough for my purposes. Editing the html file to insert some CSS isn't too hard either, if a nice-looking document would have been a requirement. Thanks!